# Pizza Class Design

Tags: design-patterns

I came across this example in Head First Design Patterns book. Pizza class has the following methods:

- prepare
- bake
- cut
- box

I believe these methods shouldn't go into the Pizza class and they should go into a separate class. Even if we ignore the fact that Single Responsibility Principle is violated, I still think these should go into a separate class (say PizzaStore).

Please comment.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want them in a different class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think it's ok if they are in the `Pizza` class, as they can represent state changes, and are thus part of the class logic:

- `bake()` could be used to change the state of the `Pizza` object. It could initially be `raw` and after the method call it could be `baked`. (haha, baked!).
- `cut()` could be used to modify the member `numberOfSlices`. Initially it could be `1`, followed by `2`,`4` and so on.

These methods are of course called from the outside, but they modify the state of the object. For me it makes sense that they are part of the class.

Answer (score 1):

It would be OK to implement factory pattern here.
Lets put some method say **bakePizza** in a class say **PizzaFactory** which returns an instance of class Pizza.

Comment: I believe a pizza, even before it's baked, is still a pizza.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That's more of a philosophical question.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want a factory. Can't you just create instances... Why use design patterns unless they are called for? Do you have any arguments?